# java gnu getopt - how to make it case insensitive?

Tags: java, getopt-long

I'm using gnu's getopt library for java. How can I make the long opts to be case insensitive? i.e. I want `--switch` to be treated like `--Switch`. The default behavior seems to be case sensitive, and I failed to find the place to define otherwise.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

getopt is written by and (mostly) for linux CLI programs. Linux is a case-sensitive operating system. In short get-opt does not supply this functionality. HOWEVER, you can work around this.

Only specify options in UPPERCASE. Before you pass your `String[]args` to getopt, loop over it and convert all options that AREN'T ARGUMENTS (e.g. start with - or --) to UPPERCASE.

Comment: I'll really re-consider if case insensitive is what I really want. Thanks!